# Facebook PHP SDK: getting "long-lived" access token now that "offline_access" is deprecated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**BASIC PROBLEM:** I want my app to be able to make calls to the Facebook graph api about authorized users even while the user is away.

For example, I want the user (A) to authorize the app, then later I want user (B) to be able to use the app to view info about user (A)'s friends. Specifically: the "work" field. Yes, I am requesting those extended permissions (`user_work_history`, `friends_work_history`, etc). Currently my app has access to the logged-in user's friends work history, but not to any of the friends' work history of *other* users of the app.

**Here's what I know already:**

- Adding `offline_access` to the scope parameter is the old way and it
  no longer works.
- The new way is with "long-lived" access tokens,
  described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/). These last for 60 days.
- I need to exchange a normal access token to get the new extended token. The FB documentation says:

  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
      client_id=APP_ID&
      client_secret=APP_SECRET&
      grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
      fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN

**Here's what I don't know (and I'm hoping you can tell me):**
How do I get the extended (aka "long-lived") access token using the Facebook PHP SDK? Currently, my code looks like this:

```
$facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Is there such a thing as this?:

```
$facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();
```

If not, is this what I should be doing?

```
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$extendedAccessToken = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id={$appId}&
    client_secret={$secret}&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token={$accessToken}"
    );
```

I've tried it and it doesn't work. I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token? client_id=#######& client_secret=#########& grant_type=fb_exchange_token& fb_exchange_token=##########) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /...
```

Does it work any differently if I switch to FQL instead of the graph api? I've read through the Facebook documentation many times, but the PHP sdk is not thoroughly documented and I can't find any examples of how this should work.

Comment: The answer’s already on the page that you have linked – read it once more, carefully …

Comment: I think I know what you're referring to, and I updated the question to show what I tried (unsuccessfully). Please tell me if you're talking about something else.

Comment: If you’re using the SDK, why do you use file_get_contents? Just use Facebook::api to make the request against the Graph API.

Comment: The reason is because I don't know what I'm doing! That's why I've posted the question. I'm confused and I'm seeing a lot of conflicting information about how to get the extended access token. I figured the safest thing was to just follow the documentation exactly... but it didn't work and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Also the documentation refers to it as a "new endpoint" which made me think it was not the same as what is normally used by the sdk.

Comment: It’s a new endpoint to talk to via HTTP … has nothing to do with the SDK. Try this: $data=$facebook->api('/oauth/access_token?…PARAMETERS…'); var_dump($data);

Comment: Aha. I tried it and I get this: `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Missing redirect_uri parameter. thrown in /home/streetof/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1106`

I tried adding in `redirect_uri=example.com&` but it didn't change the error.

Comment: Update: it DOES work with `file_get_contents()`. I had some accidental white space that was causing the url to get rejected. When I echo it, it's the same token as what I've already got. It says "expires: 5615" (that's not the exact number, but it's close.)

Comment: CORRECTION: It says "expires: 5164507"... which is 60 days... so I think this is on the right track.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I finally figured this out on my own. The answer is pretty anti-climactic. It appears that newly created apps get 60 day access tokens automatically. I'm not sure if this is dependent on enabling the "depricate offline_access" setting in the Migrations section of the app settings. Leave it on to be safe.

So at the time of writing this, you can use the PHP SDK as follows: `$facebook->getAccessToken();`

(The reason my app wasn't working as expected was unrelated to the expiration of the access token.)

Just one more thing, to get long-lived access token using PHP SDK you should call `$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();` before `$facebook->getAccessToken();`

Comment: I was using an older sdk. It didn't have the setExtendedAccessToken function you mentioned so I realized I should switch to the newest version. Now it works, thanks!

Comment: I'm getting mad on this.. I've a doubt:
you're doing this because you want to access the user profile even when he's not logged, right? But what happens when the 'extended' 60 days lasting token expires? Does the user need to reauthenticate..?
Not a great experience, I guess..

Comment: lol - I guess that explains why everything was working correctly, UNTIL I tried creating a NEW app, then generating the token from that! (With the OLD app, I get non-expiring, with the NEW app, I get 60-days!)

Comment: I think the 60 days is a red herring.  Maybe this answer is old, but calling `$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();` before `$facebook->getAccessToken();` did the trick!

Comment: Btw, the API has changed https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md#extending-the-access-token

Answer (score 23):

In the last Facebook PHP SDK 3.2.0  you have a new function `setExtendedAccessToken()`
that you have to call before `getAccessToken();`

Like this:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken(); //long-live access_token 60 days
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Answer (score 12):

Actually newly created apps only get a 60 day access token automatically if you are using a server side call. If you are using the client-side endpoint as shown above in the question, even new apps will still receive a short-term token initially. see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/

I had the same HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error that you had when using the New Endpoint and the problem was if you copy the code Facebook gives you exactly and paste it into your app, there are actually spaces in between the params, meaning there's unnecessary spaces in the url and it won't get called correctly when passed into file_get_contents() even though it works okay when pasted in the browser. This took me way too long to figure out. Hope this helps somebody! Here is my complete working code to get the extended access token out of the new endpoint (replace x's with your values):

```
$extend_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$resp = file_get_contents($extend_url);

parse_str($resp,$output);

$extended_token = $output['access_token'];

echo $extended_token;
```

Comment: I can't verify this but it's the first problem I saw in the question

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is now outdated. Here are Facebook's instructions to swap a short-term token (provided in front-end) for a long-term token (server only):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/

```
Generate a Long-lived User or Page Access Token
You will need the following:

A valid User or Page Access Token
Your App ID
Your App Secret
Query the GET oath/access_token endpoint.

curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={your-access-token}" 

Sample Response
{
  "access_token":"{long-lived-access-token}",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 5183944            //The number of seconds until the token expires
}
```